# count and show elements that are shared in at least 2 lists in R

Tags: r

I have 4 lists with different elements. How can I extract and count the number of elements that are shared in at least 2 lists and more?

For example:

```
a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
  b=c(1,4,5,7,8)
  c=c(2,5,9,10)
  d=c(11,12,13,14)
```

The answer should be: 4 counts for elements 1,2,4 and 7.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer (and recommend) to work with lists of vectors,

```r
L <- list(a,b,c,d)
```

This will get your "2 or more" elements:

```r
uniq <- sort(unique(unlist(L)))
uniq
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
uniq[rowSums(sapply(L, `%in%`, x = uniq)) > 1]
# [1] 1 2 4 5 7
```

And I think you forgot the `5` :-)

Answer (score 3):

First, I keep only unique values for each list (in case of duplicated values in same vector), then put everything into one vector. Then, I return the unique duplicates.

```
x <- unlist(lapply(list(a, b, c, d), unique))

x
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  1  4  5  7  8  2  5  9 10 11 12 13 14

sort(unique(x[duplicated(x)]))
# [1] 1 2 4 5 7
```

However, if you want the number of lists that the value shows up in, then we can use `table`.

```
table(x)[table(x) >= 2]

x
1 2 4 5 7 
2 2 2 3 2
```

Or you can also just return the names using `table` as well:

```
as.numeric(names(table(x))[table(x) >= 2])
```

If you want to return items that appear more than two times (i.e., here I set it to 3 times), then you can use `tabulate` to determine how many times a value appears.

```
unique(x)[tabulate(match(x, unique(x)))==3]
# [1] 5
```

Or you can still use table and just adjust the desired number of times that a value appears.

```
as.numeric(names(table(x))[table(x) == 3])
# [1] 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use a named list, `stack` them together and obtain the counts:

```
my_list <-list(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)
subset(aggregate(ind~values, unique(stack(my_list)), length), ind>=2, values, drop = TRUE)
[1] 1 2 4 5 7
```

or even:

```
unique(subset(unique(stack(my_list)), duplicated(values), values, drop=TRUE))
[1] 1 4 5 7 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```r
which(table(sapply(c(a,b,c,d), unique)) >= 2)

#> 1 2 4 5 7 
#> 1 2 4 5 7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
v <- rle(sort(unlist(lapply(c(a, b, c, d), unique))))

v
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:14] 2 2 1 2 3 1 2 1 1 1 ...
#   values : num [1:14] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

v$values[v$lengths >= 2]
# [1] 1 2 4 5 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R one-liner (given `lst <- list(a, b, c, d)`)

```
> as.numeric(names(which(rowSums(table(stack(setNames(lst, seq_along(lst))))) >= 2)))
[1] 1 2 4 5 7
```